# How to sort a PriorityQueue with bool and date in java

Tags: priority-queue

How can you sort a PriorityQueue that all object with a bool with a 'true' value will be always on the top  and the other with false value at the bottom and sorted with the date.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.*;

import static java.text.DateFormat.*;
import static java.util.Locale.*;

public class Patient implements Comparable<Patient> {

    private String name;
    private Date termin;
    private boolean emergency;

    Patient(String name, Date termin, boolean emergency) {
        this.name = name;
        this.termin = termin;
        this.emergency = emergency;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String  toString()
    {

        if (emergency)
        {
            return  "** Notfall! ** \t "+ this.name;
        }
        else
        {
            DateFormat df = getDateInstance(SHORT, GERMANY);
            DateFormat tf = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(SHORT,GERMANY);
            return  df.format(this.termin)+" "+tf.format(this.termin)+" \t "+this.name;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Patient o) {
        int i = 0;/*
        if (this.equals(null)|| o.equals(null))
        {
           i= 0;
        }

        if ( this.emergency == o.emergency)
        {
            if(this.termin.getTime() < o.termin.getTime()){
               i=1;
            }else{
                i= -1;
            }
        }
        if (this.emergency || o.emergency)
        {
            i= -1;
        }


        return i;*/
    }
}
```

RESULT:
(is not sorted right )

```
Warteschlange: 

 at.htl.WaitingRoom@5cad8086 

Nächster Patient: ** Notfall! **     Ralph

Nächster Patient: ** Notfall! **     anonym

Nächster Patient: 21.10.11 09:15     Antonia Adam

Nächster Patient: 21.10.11 08:30     Cäcilia Chlum

Nächster Patient: 21.10.11 09:30     Bert Bauer
```

The result  should be like this:

Warteschlange:

```
 at.htl.WaitingRoom@5cad8086 

Nächster Patient: ** Notfall! **     Ralph

Nächster Patient: ** Notfall! **     anonym

Nächster Patient: 21.10.11 08:30     Cäcilia Chlum

Nächster Patient: 21.10.11 09:15     Antonia Adam

Nächster Patient: 21.10.11 09:30     Bert Bauer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to first sort by emergencies, second by date:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Patient o) {
    if(emergency && !o.emergency)
        return -1;
    if(!emergency && o.emergency)
        return 1;
    // at this point emergency == o.emergency
    // since Java 7 you can return Long.compare(termin.getTime(), o.termin.getTime()) instead of the following:
    if(termin.getTime() < o.termin.getTime())
        return -1;
    if(termin.getTime() > o.termin.getTime())
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```